How do i get a list of articles that have been published in the last week?
I'm using Umbraco 13 and want to provide a 'latest articles' feature.
I had been using a content item on my document type for 'publish start date' and 'publish end date' that I was using to control visibility and that I could use to pull the x most recent articles based on their publish start date.
Our users have now discovered, and now prefer to use the in-built 'Publish At' and 'Unpublish At' dates for scheduling the display of their pages, which now means that I have to either double up on those fields (and hope that the users select the same dates for my custom fields and the umbraco fields), prevent the users from using standard umbraco scheduling features in favour of my custom ones, or find and use the 'publish at' and 'unpublish at' dates to replace my custom fields.
Doubling up the fields is asking for trouble - I'm already seeing cases where different dates are being used for my field and the 'publish at' date, and if I'm honest, from a support perspective, I'd rather let them use core Umbraco stuff over custom stuff wherever possible.
With that in mind, does anyone know how I can read the 'publish at' and 'unpublish at' dates for the descendant pages of a given ancestor page?
My existing code looks like this:
var articles = page.Descendants("Article")
    .Where(t => t.Value<DateTime>("publishStartDate") <= DateTime.Now.Date &&
                t.Value<DateTime>("publishEndDate") >= DateTime.Now.Date &&
                t.IsPublished() &&
                t.IsVisible())
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Value<bool>("featured"))
    .ThenByDescending(t => t.Value<DateTime>("publishStartDate"))
    .Take(4)
    .ToList();

If I'm just using Umbraco features, I can remove the checks for the current date to be between publishStartDate and publishEndDate as this would be covered by the IsPublished() and IsVisible() extensions.  The piece I'm stuck on is the sorting by publishStartDate, as I can't find the date to replace this with, so that I can take the top 4 articles.

Since the publishStartDate and publishEndDate checks can be replaced by Umbraco’s scheduling, you can just use the ContentService to get the internal "Publish At" date for each article and then sort by that.
@using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Services
@inject IContentService contentService 

var articles = page.Descendants("Article")
    .Where(t => t.IsPublished() && t.IsVisible())
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Content = t,
        PublishAt = contentService.GetById(t.Id)
        ?.ContentSchedule?.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Culture == null)?.Date
    })
    .Where(x => x.PublishAt != null)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Content.Value<bool>("featured"))
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.PublishAt)
    .Select(x => x.Content)
    .Take(4)
    .ToList();

